# QGIS: How do you overlap shapefile and raster with different coordinate systems?

Tags: qgis, raster, coordinate-system, shapefile

I have a shapefile created from a GPS log and containing long/lat data in the WGS 1984 format.  I would like to overlay it on a raster (.tif) that has the following metadata:

Spatial data:

```
+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=WGS72 +towgs84=0,0,4.5,0,0,0.554,0.2263 +units=m +no_defs
```

Layer extent:

```
5516499.9999999925494194,4837799.9999999403953552 : 5542600.0000000819563866,4860000.0000000167638063
```

Google satellite aligns perfectly with the shapefile, but the shapefile and Google satellite are about 354 meters due west of the raster.

Comment: If Croatia, layer may be using EPSG:3907 (MGI 1901 / Balkans zone 5), which would need a +towgs84 in its definition like +towgs84=551.7,162.9,467.9,6.04,1.96,-11.38,-4.82

Answer (score 4):

That is too easy!!! I love QGIS because of it!

It is called "Enable 'on the fly' CRS transformation (OFT)". You then need to define the proper CRS for each layer.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the response .... I have tried OFT to no avail.  Here's what I tried: (1) select the raster properties, and choose `selected CRS (EPSG:4326, WGS 84)` and then the raster immediately disappears from the canvas, while the shape file remains.  Alternatively, (2) I select the shape file properties and choose `+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=WGS72 +towgs84=0,0,4.5,0,0,0.554,0.2263 +units=m +no_defs` and then the shapefile disappears from the canvas while the raster remains.  Any suggestions what I'm doing wrong here?

Comment: @sschultz what you did there is *setting* the layers CRS; to change it properly, you have to *reproject* it (second option in my answer)! example: imagine a point with the coordinates 52°N 13° in degree - that`s around Berlin. now, if you *set* the CRS of this point to UTM, 52 and 13 are treated **as meter** - now you can see [Null Island](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Island) from that point. *reprojecting* that point would calculate the proper values between those coordinates. undo what you have done, reload those layers in QGIS and use the option in one of the answers here.

Comment: Thanks, but still no success.  I right-clicked the _shapefile_, chose `Save As...` and then for `CRS` I chose `+proj=utm +zone=33 +ellps=WGS72 +towgs84=0,0,4.5,0,0,0.554,0.2263 +units=m +no_defs` which is the spatial data for the raster.  Then what happened is that the _shapefile_ units were converted from long/lat to UTM, but the position of the _shapefile_ did not change.  It is still about 354 meters due west of the raster.

Comment: If I create a _shapefile_ using long/lat in the Croatia format within Trimble Pathfinder Office Export Utility, then the _shapefile_ aligns perfectly to the raster, no changes necessary.  But WGS 1984, the units of my large dataset, plots at around 354 meters due west.

Comment: @sschultz one thing is setting the CRS for the project (the screenshot I posted and it is there where you select the OFT option) and another is setting the CRS for each layer. If you set the CRS for the layers without the OTF option in the project, they will not match. Once you have the OFT for the project and your layer do not match, then you have a wrong assumption of the layer CRS. A good practice is having a WMS layer as background, so you easily catch up which one is wrong.

Comment: Some tips about a WMS from the OpenStreetMap project: https://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/QGIS#QGIS_2:_Importing_OSM_vector_layers

Comment: CRS for the project, the raster, and the shapefile are the same.  The DOF for the WMS layer aligns perfectly with the raster but is 354 meters east of the shapefile.  The GoogleEarth satellite layer from QuickMapServices aligns perfectly with the shapefile 354 meters west of the raster and WMS DOF.  Any idea what is going wrong here??  Would love to post an answer -- have been working on this for several days.

Comment: It seems we are in front of an oxymoron: "the WMS layer aligns perfectly with the raster but is 354 meters east of the shapefile".

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/78248/discussion-between-sschultz-and-marco).

Answer (score 4):

Two options:

- QGIS has a handy *on-the-fly* reprojection (*OTF*) option that will reproject all open files/layers into the designated CRS *in-memory* (i.e. metadata stays untouched). For visualization purposes, this does an amazingly easy job; chances are *OTF* is disabled in your project settings:
  `Ctrl - Shift - p`, the usual shortcut, or, if not set, `Project` -> `Project Properties` -> `CRS`
  and check `Enable On-the-fly CRS Transformation` and choose CRS
  (Note: location and naming depends somewhat on the QGIS version in use, but you´ll find that option somewhere there...)
- Alternatively, you can alter the data´s CRS directly to fit each
  other, e.g. **either**

  - right-click the *shapefile* layer -> `Save as...` -> choose name and matching CRS
  - `Raster` -> `Projections` -> `Transform (Reproject)` -> choose name and matching CRS

Note that the second option will change the metadata of your layers; this can be useful if you plan on doing further work, especially spatial analysis, on those layers since many, if not all tools will need all input layers to be in the same CRS to get proper results (most will actually throw an error).

This equally applies to symbology and labeling, e.g. if you work with *layer units*; being new to this, it can sometimes be tedious to trace errors or strange behaviour back to different CRS. For simple visualization, however, *OTF* is gold.